# Why am I getting 404 not found?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using the mean stack and I am trying to delete pictures but having a problem and I am getting a '404 not found' error. Everything seems to line up correctly but for some reason it's not working. Can anyone see why? Here is what I have:

HTML

```
<ul >
<li ng-repeat="photo in photos"><img ng-src="img/{{ photo.url}}" />

 <button class="button btn btn-warning" ng-click="deletePics(photo._id)">Delete</button>

 </li>
```

Angularjs

```
  $scope.deletePics = function(id){
    $http.delete('/api/admin/photos/' + id)
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
            },
            function errorcallback(error){
                console.log(error);
            });


  };
```

Nodejs/Expressjs

```
//delete photos
apiRoutes.delete('/admin/photos/:id'),function(req,res){
    console.log('deleted photos');
    res.send('this works');

};
```

Also, api index.js is using apiroutes as api

```
var apiRoutes = require('./apiRoute');
app.use('/api',apiRoutes);
```

Comment: now explains that /api is being used.

Comment: Inspect actual request in dev tools for clues

Comment: You may need to use method-override middleware. https://github.com/expressjs/method-override